# Does preadditive category require locally smallness?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

In general, people define a category $\mathscr{A}$ to be preadditive if for every $A,A'\in\mathscr{A}$ the collection $\mathscr{A}(A,A')$ has an abelian group structure. However, definitions in numerous sources online (like wiki, nlab, stacks project) all seems to not require the category to be $\textit{locally small}$. But if $\mathscr{A}$ is not locally small, then some hom-sets are not necessary set-worth, so it makes no sense to give them an abelian $\textit{group}$ structure. So do people just loosen their terminology to say a collection is an abelian group even if the collection is not a set?

Answer (score 3):

The standard convention is that categories are locally small by default. I don't understand your claim about online sources; in fact the [Stacks project definition of a category (tag 0013)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0013) requires that categories be *small*, except for a specific collection of exceptions, which I personally find bizarre.

In any case an abelian group must have an underlying set so a preadditive category must in particular be locally small.